# Install latest version of Node.js using NPM on AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm

Trying to update Node.js with the latest stable version by running the commands

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n stable
```

When I run the second command I get an SSL error

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/n
npm ERR! Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:409:26)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:185:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1445:7)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete [as onHeadersComplete] (http.js:111:23)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1356:20)
npm ERR!     at CleartextStream.CryptoStream._push (tls.js:396:27)
npm ERR!     at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:751:20)
npm ERR!     at EncryptedStream.CryptoStream.write (tls.js:131:13)
npm ERR!     at Socket.ondata (stream.js:38:26)
npm ERR!  [Error: SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED]
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! cwd /home/ec2-user/node/library
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.1
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.33
npm ERR! message SSL Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
npm ERR!
```

If I type `npm config ls` I have the following configuration:

```
; cli configs

; userconfig /home/ec2-user/.npmrc
ca = ""
registry = "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
strict-ssl = false

; node install prefix = undefined
; node bin location = /usr/local/bin/node
; cwd = /home/ec2-user/node/library
; HOME = /home/ec2-user
; 'npm config ls -l' to show all defaults.
```

I am new to Node.js, NPM and AWS so it might be me doing a silly mistake and needs to be pointed out by someone who has experience in setting it up.

Comment: I could suggest to use something more recent like NVM (Node Version Manager) https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Comment: Can i know the Linux version and how did you install node/npm initially? Can you try `sudo npm config ls`to check it has the `strict-ssl = false` too?

Comment: Version of linux is Linux 4.1.10-17.31.amzn1.x86_64 x86_64, the output of the config ls is posted on the question, the strict-ssl is set to false. Originally I've installed it by going directly to the github repository and checking out the version which is v0.8.1

Comment: Should I do a git pull for the latest version of node ? Instead of doing it via NPM

Comment: I would avoid installing it from source. There are tons of packages pre-compiled https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/ and NVM is by the way the best solution available imho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I trashed the original instance and created a new instance and this time I've installed node.js using the command that is on their website:

```
sudo yum install nodejs npm --enablerepo=epel
```

Instead of installing it from source as I did the first time. By executing the command above I ensured that I installed the latest version instead of an outdated version which I believe caused my problems with CERT_UNTRUSTED.

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy by any chance?
If so, try `npm --https-proxy=<your proxy> install -n`